# How to ensure s3fs is completely downloading files?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3fs

We are using s3fs to mount an S3 bucket as a local file system. It works great. My question though is, when accessing the files on S3 (via the local mount), how do we ensure that the file is completely downloaded?

For example, if we were using local storage, I could access a file (in PHP) using `file_get_contents('path/to/file')`, and the command would throw an error if the file was not accessed properly.

When using S3 bucket as a local file system, I can still access a file using `file_get_contents('path/to/file')`. But how can I ensure that s3f3 completely downloaded the file and did not only partially download the file? Will `file_get_contents` throw an error in such a situation or do I need to check md5 hashes? Is there some way to get md5 hashes of the remote files while using s3f3?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does not implement partial reading for local files. If it doesn't return `false` on error, I'd suspect it's a bug in the s3fs driver itself.